# Is there ever a scenario in SQL where an index would be detrimental?

Tags: sql, indexing

Can an index ever hurt? That's my whole question. I'm curious.

Comment: Would you consider suboptimal detrimental?

Comment: Yes. Anything that isn't beneficial.

Comment: Types and number of indexes should be well thought out in a database.  Indexes can be very large so space becomes a consideration.

Comment: @paqogomez if there is plenty of space, will they ever slow down a query?

Answer (score 3):

Query optimizers will simply ignore indexes that are irrelevant to a query. But they still have to spend some microseconds during query optimization, considering whether each index should be used.

The more indexes you have on a table, the more complex the optimizer's job to analyze which is the best one to use. In some rare cases, the optimization phase could actually be more costly than the query execution.

I worked on a case recently helping a client using MySQL 5.6, in which some new sophisticated query optimization features caused the query to use 100% CPU during optimization. Basically, it caused the optimizer to estimate the benefit of thousands of permutations of index choices, like a chess-playing program looking ahead several moves.

To solve this problem, we changes some configuration variables effectively to make MySQL 5.6's optimizer skip its new features, and be dumber about optimal index choice, like it was in MySQL 5.5. This solved the CPU spike issue in that case.

That case was exceptional because the query was very complex, and they had many indexes.

This case was also very specific to one version of one brand of RDBMS. But other brands of database may have similar edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indexes can hurt.  First, there is overhead in maintaining the index during inserts, updates, and deletes.  This overhead can be detrimental, particularly in high-volume transactional environments.

Indexes may also be used incorrectly.  For instance, the following query can be quite hard to optimize:

```
select t.*
from table t
where col1 > 'x'
order by col2
```

when there are two indexes, one on `col1` and the other on `col2`.

One approach is to use the `col1` index to fetch all the appropriate rows.  Then use a sort for the `order by`.  Another approach is to use the `col2` index for the ordering and then filter one row at a time.

Which approach is better depends on the *data*, and it can be hard for an optimizer to always make the right decision.  This is a case where having a second index can mean that the wrong index is used for optimization.

In general, indexes do help with query optimization and for many systems, the additional overhead of maintaining them is negligible.  But, this doesn't mean that they are always helpful.